# how to show data from joined tables in DJANGO DRF

Tags: django

I'm trying to show data from a table that has several ForeignKey fields assigned to it:

```
class Promotion (models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User)
    Rating = models.ForeignKey(Rating)
    Date_Effective = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Rating.Rank.Short_Rank + ' ' + self.User.last_name + ' (' + str(self.Date_Effective) + ')'

class Rating (models.Model):
    Rank = models.ForeignKey(Rank)
    Genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre)
    Branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch)
    Image = models.FileField(upload_to='ranks')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Rank.Display_Rank + " (" + self.Branch.Branch + "; " + self.Genre.Short_Term + ")"
```

I'm trying to build a serializer that shows the Rating.**str** value from it and User information.

```
class PromotionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    Rating = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    users = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Promotion
        fields = ('Date_Effective', 'Rating', 'users')
```

This results in error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError at /member/api/promotions/
Exception Value: 'Rating' object is not iterable
```

I'm trying to figure this thing out.  How do I do this?
Thanks much.

Comment: Try to set `many=False` in `Rating = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)`

Comment: ok.  I got a failure for user now.  I took out user to get `
{
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/member/api/promotions/2/",
    "Date_Effective": "2017-03-18",
    "Rating": 2
}`  How do I get the Rating `__str__` value, instead of the pk number.  Then how do I get it for user?  Thanks.

Comment: defined rating using SerializerMethodField: `Rating = serialisers.SerializerMethodField()` and `def get_rating(self, obj): return str(obj)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking Django Rest Framework to return the primary key of the related object in `PromotionSerializer` by using `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`.

If you want it to return the unicode representation of the object, try using `StringRelatedField` instead: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield.

In addition, as one of your comments mentions, you should not use `many=True` (no need to set it to false, just remove the argument).

Note: It's unconventional to use Title Case when naming attributes of classes in Python. Title case is normally reserved for class names themselves.

Comment: Thanks much!!  Appreciate it.